# How to convert simple String into local DateTime format in java

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, date

I am trying to convert string `"20190207000115"` into DateTime format like `2019-02-07 00:01:15` in java.

Is there any method in java to convert into day time format like this ? So far I found in C# but not in java.

Please help me

Comment: Use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` .

Comment: Thanks Mark for reply, Can you please share code syntax ?

Comment: @user3302083 Search and you shall find. However, `LocalDateTime.parse("20190207000115", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss"))` yields a `LocalDateTime` of `2019-02-07T00:01:15`. If you want it printed in a different format, for example without the `T` in the middle, use a second `DateTimeFormatter`. Search for how.